# Trying to get company name from meta title of the website. I need to remove any word that does not match the domain name with proper spacing

Tags: python, web-scraping

so this is my challenge, i need to get the company name of a domain with proper spacing.

Example of a company domain:

https://imperiodasmilhas.com/

The company name is "imperio das milhas". So i need to get this name with proper spacing somehow from the company website.

I can get this information from the meta title of the website:

Imperio das Milhas - Tudo sobre milhas bem aqui!

But the problem is that the title will come with extra words that i don't want. like "tudo sobre milhas bem aqui".

Is there any possible regex to extract the

"imperio das milhas" output from this meta title:

" Imperio das Milhas - Tudo sobre milhas bem aqui!"

One way i thought to to do this is identify the first 3 letters of the domain, and remove everything before. And identify the 3 last letters of the domain and remove everything after. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not take the title and remove the "-" and everything after it with something like:

```
x = "Imperio das Milhas - Tudo sobre milhas bem aqui!"
y = x.split("-") # or maybe " - "??
print(y[0]) # prints "Imperio das Milhas"
```